# require() inside require()'d file

Tags: webpack

My webpack config compiles my .scss files to CSS in a pretty standard way:

```
    {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass']
    }
```

What I'd like to do, though, is have url and file loaders work inside the *.scss files, with the end goal of inlining my smaller images:

```
&.backdrop {
    background-image: require('../../assets/images/backdrop-1.jpg');
}
```

It seems that webpack is ignoring the require() call, though, as the CSS that results is identical to the code above (i.e. the browser is told to try and render a background image found at `require('../../' [etc etc]`. This is the loader I've been trying for the above:

```
    {
        test: /\.jpg$/,
        loader: 'url',
        query: {
            limit: 250000
        }
    }
```

Can anyone suggest where I'm going wrong?